# vim plugin command w/o a buffer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I have a problem with many vim commands that come from plugins. They don't within an empty buffer.

For example :Gstatus from fugitive plugin doesn't work when in a new tab/buffer.

The strangest thing though is that initially, just after running vim, it works. i.e. if I just run vim and type :Gstatus it will work. but if before that I do :newtab or :enew it will not work.

The difference that I see that the first open buffer seems to be in a [Rails] mode, and the new ones are not.

Answer (score 1):

These commands work on files and/or directories. When doing `:tabnew` you don't open a file or a directory. Since fugitive is only a (nice) wrapper around `git`, doing `:Gstatus` is like doing `$ git status` in your "Pictures" folder: it's not a git repository so git does nothing.

You could try to `:cd` to an actual git repository and do `:Gstatus` there.

Comment: I AM starting vim from an actual .git repository.

Also, you didn't read my question in full. when I start vim from a top directory of a Rails project - the empty buffer is in [Rails] mode and Gstatus is available, and yes, it works over current directory which is a repository.

but... once I do :tabnew, the new tab is NOT in a [Rails] mode.

Comment: actually, I don't think Gstatus availability is related to Rails mode in any way. if I start vim in non-rails project repository - the initial tab still does have Gstatus and a new one still doesn't. but my guess is that whatever was initializing Rails mode is also initializing fugitive on the initial tab and fails to do so on new ones.

Comment: Please read my answer again. It doesn't matter where you are **before** you open a new buffer/tab: in vim, an empty buffer/tab is **nothing**, it doesn't represent anything in your file system, it's completely virtual. It starts to be "something" when you save its content as an actual file in your filesystem. For the `:Gstatus` command to work you **must** be in a git repository but your new buffer/tab is probably not: type `:pwd` to see where you are from Vim's point of view. If Rails.vim doesn't change it your working directory will be either the default one (`$HOME`) either the last one...

Comment: well, what about the initial buffer when I just start vim? What does it represent? :) :Gstatus and other plugin commands work in it. The only thing Gstatus needs is current directory and this is available in any tab and is not changing.